# Stop and start NSThread in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a thread with a `runLoop` inside thread's main function which is working right. This `runLoop` is inside a while loop which will iterate if cancelled is false.

```
public override func main() {

    super.main()

    var runLoop: NSRunLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
    do {
        runLoop.run()
    } while(!self.cancelled)
    NSLog("Thread stopped")
    NSThread.exit()
}
```

When I set cancel flag to the thread (through `NSTreah.cancel()` method), the thread appears to successfully end, as I get *Thread stopped* in the console, but when I try to start the thread again I am always getting `attempt to start the thread again`. How can I restart the thread without getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot restart a thread. That's a fundamental concept of multithreaded programming, a thread runs once and when it's been stopped it does not restart. Simply create a new object instead.